# How to link the accordion panel text to the hidden accordion menu tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jtabbedpane

I have my accordion built and working, however, I am having trouble with how to make the content in the MyChannel tabbed panel do what I want.

Under the Accordion tab "MyChannel" are 4 lines of text: (Account, Payments, Uploads, Upgrade). How can I make these lines turn to links that when click can open their corresponding accordion tab above. Also I dont want the corresponding tabs to never show. I want them hidden even when selected by the link. The only three Accordion items to be shown is: On Now, Beans, and MyChannel.

Here is my code I have been trying to figure out. I tried to simplify it. Thanks.

```
<div id="controls"></div>
<div id="Profile" class="tabcontent"></div>

<div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'OnNow')">On Now</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Beans')">Beans</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'MyChannel')">MyChannel</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'AccountInfo')">Account Info</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Payments')">Payments</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'MyUploads')">MyUploads</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Upgrade')">Upgrade</button>
</div>

<div id="OnNow" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>OnNow</h3>
 <p>On Now is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Beans" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>Beans</h3>
 <p>Beans is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>  

<div id="MyChannel" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>My Channel</h3>
 <p>Account Info<Br>Payments<Br>My Uploads <Br>Upgrade Your Channel </p>
</div>

<div id="AccountInfo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Account Info</h3>
</div>

<div id="Payments" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Payments</h3>
</div>

<div id="MyUploads" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>My Uploads</h3>
</div>

<div id="Upgrade" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>Upgrade</h3>
</div>


<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Thanks Again.

Oh here is the CSS

```
.tab {
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
background-color: inherit;
float: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px 16px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
display: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should remove the buttons you simply dont need them.
2. Use the a Tags in order to make your text clickable.
3. You can user the href attribute inside the a tags in order to call JS functions.

`<a href='javascript:openCity(event, "AccountInfo",true)'>Account Info</a>`

[Test it here](https://jsfiddle.net/9td1099p/2/)

Comment: Cool. It was the a href I kept getting wrong. I didn't use a java script. I was just link directly to the tab id. Thanks